# PHP show either IPv4 or IPv6 in the main page

Tags: php, html, apache, ipv6, ipv4

For testing purposes, i would like Apache (+php) main page to show either IPv4 or IPv6 client and server (real and used in url) IP addresses.

For IPv4 I use the following php code:

> echo "Local server IP = ".$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
>
> echo "IP used by client = ".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
>
> echo "DNS name used by client = ".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

Cannot find equivalent IPv6 variables to show IPv6 or IPv4 depending on the protocol the client browser is using.

Comment: HTTP_HOST shows the hostname in the URL the client used. Most of the time that's not an IP address

Comment: There are no such variables. SERVER_ADDR already shows either IPv4 or IPv6 depending on what the client connected to